# Relationship between density of Schwartz functions and separability.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

**Context** *(not necessary for the question)*: I've come across a very interesting duality theorem regarding $L^1$-based Besov spaces which states that these can be identified as the dual space to the completion of the Schwartz functions under some Holder-Zygmund norm. I work in PDEs, so I'd really love for the weak-* topology on (*Edit:* norm-bounded subsets of) these Besov spaces to be metrizable, which would follow from showing their preduals are separable. For some reason I expect the answer to the question below to be very simple if it is true, but I just can't figure it out.

**My Question:** If $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach space of functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $S(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $X$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|$, under what additional conditions does it follow $X$ is separable?

---

So I've answered what I've needed in my context: I know specifically that my $X^*$ is separable in the dual-norm topology, which turns out to be key because this means $X$ has to be separable in its topology w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|$, which then implies dual-norm-bounded subsets of $X^*$ are metrizable, which is what I wanted. *However*, I still think it'd be an interesting question to answer.

Comment: On general grounds, very unlikely for a weak-dual(star) topology to be (complete?) metrizable. But maybe that's not what you intend to ask...

Comment: @paulgarrett Right, I'm just sort of being hopeful! In the Besov range, the weak-* topology is metrizable for all $p\in(1,\infty]$, so I'm thinking it wouldn't necessarily be a surprise if in this case I also ended up with what I wanted.

Comment: I may be naive about this, but doesn't the "usual proof" of (complete...) metrizability refer to a stronger topology than the weak dual? Much as the simplest cases of $L^2$ Sobolev spaces can give negatively-indexed ones their Hilbert-space (=strong) topologies... but could also give them the weak-dual topologies... which are much weaker, etc.? Can you clarify? Maybe I'm not understanding your context...

Comment: (And, yes, I do know arguments for the "quasi-completeness" of even very-weak-dual topologies, but that maybe is not what you're asking about? Or is it?)

Comment: @paulgarrett Ah thank you for pointing this out, I mean I want the weak-* topology on norm-bounded subsets of $X^*$ to be metrizable. Basically, my desire is to have the equivalence for norm-bounded sequences that weak-* precompactness is the same as sequential weak-* precompactness. So if I'm understanding your comment correctly, then no I'm not looking for complete metrizability of the weak dual topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a separable topological space and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous into another topological space with dense image, then $Y$ is again separable because, for a countable $X$-dense subset $S\subseteq X$ you have
$$ \overline{f(S)}^Y=\overline{f(\overline S^X)}^Y =\overline{f(X)}^Y=Y.$$

Since $\mathscr S(\mathbb R^d)$ with its usual Fréchet topology is separable you need the continuity of the inclusion into your Banach space -- in all *natural* situations, this should follow from the closed graph theorem, for example, it automatically holds if norm-convergence implies pointwise convergence for your Banach space of functions.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Don't you need something like the assumption that $f$ is surjective in the first part of the answer?

Comment: @RhysSteele Since it was assumed in the question I forgot to state it in my answer: You need of course that the image $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$. I corrected the answer accordingly.